# What's the easiest way to use Create React App with Relay?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, create-react-app

I would like to use `create-react-app` without ejecting my Relay app.

According to [Relay documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html#usage) I will need the `babel-relay-plugin`. The `relay-starter-kit` configures this in a [.babelrc](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-starter-kit/blob/f3025cee82eacc0fbfb66cec075b3691663d0b9f/.babelrc).

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? Is there a way to enable `relay` without ejecting?

Answer (score 6):

## Create React App v2

CRA 2 supports Babel macros which makes things a whole lot easier. Essentially you have to add `babel-plugin-relay` and use it with `import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro'`. [Check out the docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/1ae90a18e779d1b51dc0b8f0330ba0b9ecd3fe36/docusaurus/docs/adding-relay.md) for more information.

## Create React App v1

One option is to create your own fork of `react-scripts` that adds `babel-relay-plugin` to `.babelrc`. Creating a fork of `react-scripts` is documented as [method #3 in this Medium post](https://medium.com/@shubheksha/tweaking-configuration-for-react-scripts-in-create-react-app-d91e9d03a42f#3481). You can publish the fork as a [scoped package to npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages) and then use that when creating your React app: `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version @scope/react-scripts`.

A different option that some might prefer is `react-app-rewired`: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired - I haven't looked into this myself yet, but it seems like another good way of doing it that could potentially lessen the need to keep a fork of `react-scripts` maintained.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to maintain your own fork of `react-scripts`, you can simply do the following:

#### Step 1: Install `babel-plugin-relay`

```
$ yarn add babel-plugin-relay
```

#### Step 2: Create `./setup.js` file in the root of your project

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let file = path.resolve('./node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js');
let text = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');

if (!text.includes('babel-plugin-relay')) {
  if (text.includes('const plugins = [')) {
    text = text.replace(
      'const plugins = [',
      "const plugins = [\n  require.resolve('babel-plugin-relay'),"
    );
    fs.writeFileSync(file, text, 'utf8');
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Failed to inject babel-plugin-relay in ${file}.`);
  }
}
```

#### Step 3: Update scripts in `package.json` to run `node setup` first

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node setup && react-scripts build",
  "test": "node setup && react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "start": "node setup && react-scripts start"
}
```

For a complete **Relay Modern** + **Create React App** example (including routing) visit:

[`kriasoft`](https://github.com/kriasoft)/**[`react-static-boilerplate`](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate)** on GitHub

Comment: You are re-assigning variable `text`, so have to declare it as `let text = ...`, I believe.

Comment: Note this is very fragile and will break in the next versions. Please don’t rely on this. I expanded on the problem here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-firebase-starter/issues/278.

Answer (score 2):

create-react-app v2 `(react-scrips >= 2.0.0)` works out the box with Relay Modern!

You just need `babel-plugin-relay >= 1.7.0`, `relay-compiler` and `graphql` as dev dependencies to compile queries

Then you need a `schema.graphql` files declaring your GraphQL types and of course `react-relay`

Before running `start` you just have to compile any queries you might have added or changed inside of graphql tags. Simply add the script to your package.json which you can also run in watch mode:

`"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql"`

Fully working example here: https://github.com/kassens/relay-cra-example

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/462 between @gaearon and @josephsavona from Relay team, they would like to push back Relay support in create-react-app to after the release of Relay 2.

Since the release of Relay 2 is already in the horizon, in the meantime, I would suggest to use a simple hack to add support to create-react-app and wait for their official release.

So for now, you can:

1. Add [babel-plugin-react-relay](https://github.com/graphcool/babel-plugin-react-relay) (trust me it is easier to setup than babel-relay-plugin) to your *package.json* *devDependencies*, setup your graphql endpoint in package.json like

   `"graphql": {
     "request": {
       "url": "http://localhost:8000/graphql"
     }
   },`

   then run `yarn`
2. Navigate to *./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js*, use *⌘+F* to locate 
   `presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],`

   Add the following line below `presets`:

   `plugins: [require.resolve('babel-plugin-react-relay')],`

   Also, turn `cacheDirectory` right after the above line off using:

   `cacheDirectory: false`

   This is to ensure that GraphQL schema is correctly refetched by *babel-plugin-react-relay* each time. And this is no harm since we will be using official create-react-app with Relay support soon :)
3. Do step 2 to *./node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js*, only in production configuration there is no cacheDirectory option
4. Run `yarn start` and you are good to go

Hope this can get you started with Relay without `yarn run eject` your code. And do remember to migrate to official Relay 2 supported create-react-app once it is released (I suspect you won't have to do anything though)

Comment: this is not great, you'll have to manually edit the webpack configs, on _every_ installation of the depedencies...and just straight up won't work in CI.

Comment: @monastic-panic never said it is ideal. I have said it is a **HACK** and basically that means if you are using this as more than just a experiment, you should not be using it. And in that case, of course you should bear the cost of maintaining your own fork of `react-scripts` as the first answer suggested. This is nothing more than a convenient way to have a taste of Relay.